# Git: How to revert a symlink commit which replaced a submodule?

Tags: git, symlink, git-submodules

I have a submodule in my main repository called `third-party`. Since this module was too big, I had created a symlink to `third-party` folder in my workspace.
To my misfortune, I have committed this symlink into my branch as part of big fat merge! Basically, I have replaced a submodule with a symlink.

I have tried to delete the link and submodule update, it didn't help.

**More details:**

`cat .gitmodules` outputs the following

```
[submodule "third-party"]
    path = third-party
    url = http://my-git-server/third-party.git
```

`ls -la` outputs the following

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  admin  136 Jul 26 17:57 some-folder
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  admin  102 Jul 26 17:57 third-party -> /some/dead/path
```

I have no idea how to recover from this situation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried multiple things and finally the following worked. Better ways to solve this are welcome!

```
#delete the symlink
rm third-party 

#delete the symlink from git 
git rm third-party

#remove the submodule
cat /dev/null>.gitmodules

#commit the changes
git add .
git commit -m "Removing third-party as submodule"

#add the submodule again
git add submodule http://my-git-server/third-party.git third-party

#get the latest code from the submodule
git submodule update --remote
```

This fixed my problem. Though the commit hash that third-party is pointing now is different, when I do `git submodule update --remote`, I get the latest code!